# When is it okay to contract two nouns to form one?

Tags: orthography, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

English doesn't really allow word contractions the way German and Dutch allow or even require. What rules, if any, are there when two nouns should contract to one or not?

e.g. Why toolchain and keychain, but then supply chain and not supplychain?